# Windows Phone 8 - Full System Backup and Restore

Tags: 8.0, contacts, backup

I have a new (Verizon) Nokia Icon (Lumia 929) Windows Phone.

I'm looking for the equivalent of a Full System Backup and Restore (including contacts) solution, similar to what you might have on a PC. By 'contacts', I'm referring to the built-in contacts list. I'm not using Outlook and/or Office 365 at the moment.

Of course, the reason is ... in case the phone bricks, crashes, has to be replaced, something gets corrputed, or some other catastrophe ... the backup could be restored to the same phone or a new phone (assume same or similar model).

There is a built 'Backup' app, but that does not backup Contacts.
There is also the built-in "Backup Assistant Plus' app, but there are currently issues with that - I have a ticket in with Verizon on that (good luck!!). In theory, it should be backing up the contact list.

There are a few 'contact backup' apps in the WindowsPhone store/web site - for example http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/contacts-backup/8fc95611-fb8a-4483-9277-864fed3fcb5e ... but none of these apps discuss Restore ... and all seem a bit ... sketchy.

So ... I welcome any ideas, suggestions and so on.

And for the moment, I will settle for just a Contacts backup/restore ... since the phone does include the 'Backup' app - which backs up settings, apps and so on. It's just not clear where on OneDrive they are going ... and how you would restore them.

DISCLAIMER (lol). This is actually my first Smart Phone (coming from an LG Env Touch!) ... so, I could be missing something regarding this subject :-)

TIA ... mx

Comment: Have you signed in to your phone with a Microsoft Account?

Comment: You really should consider moving your contact list in the cloud.

Comment: I have since synced my contacts (and calendar) between my two laptops (Outlook 2013), my Phone and both Outlook.com and my Office 365 E3 account. So ... the issue is resolved. I disabled VZN Backup Assistant Plus.  
Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your contacts are backed up with your email provider. You are not using Outlook, but Gmail, Yahoo, and other email providers will provide your contacts as well. If something happens to your phone, the email service will have the full contact list.

Comment: I do not you web based email like gMail, Yahoo etc. I have all domain email accounts associated with my websites. All of my email comes from my ISP ... into Outlook (2013).  My contacts are also in Outlook.  

At some point in the near future, I will be upload my Outlook contact list to Office/Outlook 365, and that will sync with this phone. 

But in the meantime, I'm looking to (at a minimum) back up the built-in contacts ... that was manually ported over (by Verizon store) from my LG to this phone.